# Jquery scrolltop not hiding

Tags: javascript, jquery

My scrolltop function not working. I want to hide this div.me, but it's not working

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if (scrollTop > 100) {
    $('.me').hide();
  }
});
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 200%;
  background: grey;
}

.me {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec1" class="all">
  <div class="inner myself">
    <div class="me">
      <span>Codepen</span>
      <p>Front end developer playground</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: `window.scrollTop()` try this instead of `scrollTop` https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ and for good measure you can `console.log()` the scrollTop value to double check the values returned... `console.log( window.scrollTop() );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure you would prefer a toggle - and you forgot to refer to the window - here `$(this).scrollTop()` since we are inside a window event.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  $('.me').toggle($(this).scrollTop() <= 100)
});
```

```css
html {
  min-height: 200%;
  background: grey;
}

.me {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec1" class="all">
  <div class="inner myself">
    <div class="me">
      <span>Codepen</span>
      <p>Front end developer playground</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to you compare a `function` with a `number` this will fail (you also have to use the jQuery Selector). You need to call the method (using `()`):

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){  // <-- here
    $('.me').hide();
}
});
```

```css
html{
  min-height: 200%;
  background: grey;
}
.me{
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec1" class="all">
    <div class="inner myself">
      <div class="me">
        <span>Codepen</span>
        <p>Front end developer playground</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

in your method you have to assign `$(window).scrolltop()` value to `scrollTop`
but you can directly use it like this

```js
$(window).scroll(function(){
if($(window).scrollTop() > 100){
    $('.me').hide();
}
});
```

```css
html{
  min-height: 200%;
  background: grey;
}
.me{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 40%;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="sec1" class="all">
    <div class="inner myself">
      <div class="me">
        <span>Codepen</span>
        <p>Front end developer playground</p>
    </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Comment: @messerbill i just did bro